# Need help about concurrency programming in Go

Tags: go

---

### For this task i need to find min sum in list of numbers. Then i must print number that have min sum. This must be done with Mutex and WaitGroups. I can't find where is the mistake or why is output different.
Logic: Scanf n and make vector with len(n). Then create funcion for sum of number and forward that function to second where we in one FOR cycle give goroutines function to.

I run this code a few times, and sometimes give different answer for same input.
Input:
3
13
12
11
Output:
Sometimes 12
Sometimes 11

---

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup
var mutex sync.Mutex
var vector []int
var i int
var n int
var firstsum int
var p int //Temp sum
var index_result int

func sumanajmanjih(broj int) int {
    var br int
    var suma int
    br = int(math.Abs(float64(broj)))
    suma = 0
    for {
        suma += br % 10
        br = br / 10

        if br <= 0 {
            break
        }
    }
    return suma
}
func glavna(rg int) {
    var index int
    firstsum = sumanajmanjih(vector[0])
    for {
        mutex.Lock()
        if i == n {
            mutex.Unlock()
            break
        } else {
            index = i
            i += 1
            mutex.Unlock()
        }

        fmt.Printf("Procesor %d radni indeks %d\n", rg, index)
        p = sumanajmanjih(vector[index])
        if p < firstsum {
            firstsum = p
            index_result = index
        }
    }
    wg.Done()
}
func main() {
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &n)
    vector = make([]int, n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        fmt.Scanf("%d", &vector[i])
    }
    fmt.Println(vector)
    brojGR := runtime.NumCPU()
    wg.Add(brojGR)
    for rg := 0; rg < brojGR; rg++ {
        go glavna(rg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(vector[index_result])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer to your question, but a few suggestions to make code more readable and stable:

1. Use English language for names - glavna, brojGR are hard to understand
2. Add comments to code explaining intent
3. Try to avoid shared/global variables, especially for concurrent code. `glavna(rg)` is executed concurrently, and you assign global `i` and `p` inside that function, that is a race condition. Sends all the data in and out into function explicitly as argument or function result.
4. Mutex easily can lock the code, and it is complicated to debug. Simplify its usage. Often `defer mutex.Unlock()` in the next line after `Lock()` is good enough.